# how to divide data per month with special condition

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

i have 1 table called **order_star_member**, in this table contain users_id as the users, createdAt as the date of transaction, and total_price_star_member as the amount of the transaction of each users_id. the first one i want to find out are the users id who become star member, star member are the users_id who doing transaction >= 600.000 per month. the second is, i want to grouping star member on february 2020 and grouping based on where star member come from month, here's my syntax

```
select count(distinct osm1.users_id) as jml_buyer, year(osm1.createdAt), month(osm1.createdAt) from order_star_member osm1
where osm1.createdAt >= MAKEDATE(year(osm1.createdAt), 1) + INTERVAL month(osm1.createdAt) month - interval 1 month
AND
osm1.createdAt <= MAKEDATE(YEAR(osm1.createdAt), 1) + INTERVAL month(osm1.createdAt) month- INTERVAL 1 day
AND not EXISTS (select distinct(osm2.users_id) from order_star_member osm2 where osm1.users_id = osm2.users_id
and osm2.createdAt < MAKEDATE(YEAR(osm1.createdAt), 1) + INTERVAL month(osm1.createdAt) month- INTERVAL 1 month)
and exists (select distinct(osm3.users_id) from order_star_member osm3 where osm1.users_id = osm3.users_id
and osm3.createdAt >= '2020-02-01'
and osm3.createdAt < '2020-03-01') group by month(osm1.createdAt) having sum(osm1.total_price_star_member) >= 600000;
```

and here's my fiddle

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ee605f652628518cbf5a1bf121a46360

this is data dummy

```
+----------+----------+------+-------------------------+
| users_id |  month   | year | total_price_star_member |
+----------+----------+------+-------------------------+
|        1 | January  | 2019 |                  60.000 |
|        1 | February | 2019 |                 200.000 |
|        2 | January  | 2019 |                 300.000 |
|        2 | January  | 2019 |                 400.000 |
|        1 | January  | 2019 |                 350.000 |
|        3 | January  | 2019 |                 300.000 |
|        3 | February | 2019 |                 600.000 |
|        4 | February | 2019 |                 650.000 |
+----------+----------+------+-------------------------+
```

so expected results if i want to find out the statistic of amount star member on month february are like this

```
+------+-------+-----------------+
| year | month | count(users_id) |
+------+-------+-----------------+
| 2019 |     1 |               0 |
| 2019 |     2 |               2 |
+------+-------+-----------------+
```

explaination : so based on this dummy, the statistic of month february are like that, 0 users_id in from january because there's no users_id who had transaction >= 600.000 on january who also doing transaction >= 600.000 on february, and 2 users_id from february who doing transaction >= 600.000 on february (users_id 3 and 4)

Comment: *star member are the users_id who doing transaction >= 600.000 per month* In at least one previous/current month? Or only in the month when he oversized the limit? *the first one i want* Please show desired result, and explain your one-two-group-... for each output record.

Comment: See [the fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=29112c5e5354057f287fc1c8f570bc44) with formatted query text and some comments.

Comment: oh im sorry, that fiddle was the dummy case but the syntax are the real syntax who applied on my case, let me add some expected results who related to my syntax @Akina